# With the same form, ie and firefox sent different forms, why?

Tags: .net, http, unicode, encoding, httpwebrequest

I have a form, and if I only fill in English characters, everything is OK, but if I tried to fill in some Chinese characters, then problem happens:

**If fill in the form in chrome or firefox, then it sent following request:**

/docsearch/documents/site/test/documentLibrary/?filter=path&filterData=%2F&size=50&pos=1&prop_cm_name=%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD HTTP/1.1

**If fill in the form in IE, then it sent following request:**
/doclib/docsearch/documents/site/test/documentLibrary/?filter=path&filterData=%2F&size=50&pos=1&prop_cm_name=\326\320\271\372 HTTP/1.1

As you can see, same Chinese characters can have different encoding within IE and firefox. Can someone tell me how to make IE send the same requests as firefox/chrome ?

EDIT form:

```
    <form action="" enctype="application/json" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" id="template_x002e_toolbar_x002e_documentlibrary-form" forms-runtime="listening" onsubmit="return false;">   
          <div class="form-fields" id="template_x002e_toolbar_x002e_documentlibrary-form-fields">

    <div class="form-field">
             <label for="template_x002e_toolbar_x002e_documentlibrary_prop_cm_name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" title="Name" value="" tabindex="0" name="prop_cm_name" id="template_x002e_toolbar_x002e_documentlibrary_prop_cm_name">
    </div>
    </form>
```

It seems that IE treat those characters as Unicode, but not UTF8 as per the parameter in form?

Comment: Can you post a code snippet of your form?

Comment: I posted the form, thanks in advance.

Comment: The solution is that I have to use encodeURIComponent function to manually encode those parameters.

Comment: and refer to http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/, to check different encoding functions in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to either remove the `enctype` attribute from the `form` element, or choose one of the following values for it:

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- multipart/form-data
- text/plain

The value you're using, `application/json`, might be causing the difference you're seeing, as different browsers may handle an unknown value of the `enctype` attribute differently.

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp) for more info.